# Debugging with Key Pressed

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a function that displays an object on screen when a key is pressed.  I should be able to left click this object while the key is pressed and the program makes a change to the object on the click - this is not happening.  I put a breakpoint into the left mouse click handler.  Pressed the key and clicked the object.  Switching to VS2010 I get a message that I cannot Edit and Continue at that point.  If I lift off the key press then I can debug.  However I am concerned that there may be something else reacting to the key press causing the change in the object to fail.

A quick update - if I disable the actions from the Key Up event then everything works.

My question is therefore if there is any way to debug in VS2010 with a key pressed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Tracepoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7.aspx). This will allow you to add trace messages and output the value of variables without needing to stop in the debugger. Key presses and mouse clicks will therefore not interfere with the debugger.

Comment: Thanks again - I found my problem.  I had assumed that a key down event fired only when the key is first pressed - it seems to fire repeatedly while the key is down.